# Flutter Xcode fatal error when trying to run and build into an iPhone emulator

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store

I'm trying to build the app to iOS that I am coding in Flutter. Unfortunately, there was an error and the build wont budge. The error is below. How do I fix this?

I've added Firebase to my app which fix the previous errors but this one remains.

```
Xcode build done.                                           23.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Flutter/SyncShop APP/syncshop/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'connectivity' not
    found
    @import connectivity;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Comment: did u solved this issue? I have been facing this and trying to solve but not getting any proper solution yet.

Answer (score -1):

I change this files

pubspec.yaml -> connectivity: 0.4.4+1
Podfile -> platform :ios, '9.0'

```sh
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Comment: I have the same issue. but I couldn't fix it using your answer